# Export specific columns from Access table to CSV using SELECT ... INTO

Tags: vb.net, csv, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm able to select an entire table from an Access database, into a CSV using the following code via VB.NET:

```
Dim AccessCommandCust As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * INTO [Text;DATABASE=C:\TEMP].[CUSTOMERS.csv] FROM Customers", AccessConn)
```

However, I don't need the entire table, just two columns -- Firstname and Lastname.  The SQL is simple enough, but when I attempt this using the following code:

```
Dim AccessCommandCust As New OleDbCommand("SELECT FirstName, LastName INTO [Text;DATABASE=C:\TEMP].[CUSTOMERS.csv] FROM Customers", AccessConn)
```

It raises an exception:

> Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'CUSTOMERS.csv').

I'm trying to figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: If you find so many problems with SQL strings or syntax, you could also use an adapter to fill a DataSet. Then you can only select desired columns and finally store it into csv. That is prety fast and you can manage data.

Comment: That's where I am now.  SQL on its own is fine, but this particular command doesn't seem to allow for anything other than selecting the entire table (*).  Thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

The following syntax ended-up working for me:

```
Dim AccessCommandCust As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT FirstName, LastName INTO [Text;HDR=YES;DATABASE=C:\Temp\].CUSTOMERS.csv FROM Customers", AccessConn)
```

The brackets [] around the filename itself, appear to be the issue.